# custom module links not appear after upgrading the magento. it will work on local machine but not work on live?

Tags: php, magento, module, migration

I have one big issues don't know due to my mistake or magento's structure. i have update the magento to 1.4.1.1 and all work fine on my local machine but when i have moved it to live then in admin custom module's link are not appeared .

i have also tried for clearing the cache and re login but it wont work.. can any one help??

Comment: Could you provide more details? Show config.xml file of your module.

Comment: all are working fine on our test server but not work on live :(. both sever have same configurations :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Are the Live code bases and local code bases exactly the same
2. Are you sure the live codebase is actually being used by apache
3. If your module loaded into the system?
4. Does your user have [the right ACL permissions](http://alanstorm.com/magento_acl_authentication) to view the navigation items?
5. Have you cleared your user sessions (separate from cache) to ensure that ACL permissions are flushed for the user

Finally, the class at

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Page/Menu.php
```

is the one responsible for rendering the navigation.  Investigate/debug from to to figure out why it's skipping and/or not seeing your custom navigation items.

Comment: yes all are on same place, it is running on our test server but not on client's server :P

Comment: i have finally get the solution, it is due to magento upgrade from 1.3.2.4 to 1.4.1.1, i have to put adminhtml.xl files in each extension's etc directory.. now its working

Comment: If those files were missing chances are there were other files that weren't upgraded.  At minimum I'd do a diff on your entire folder structure comparing it to a just unzipped version.

Comment: I have to placed the adminhtml.xml file, don't know why but when i have placed it in extension's etc folder the all re working fine.. but same are working on my local without that adminhtml.xml file..

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this is often caused by caseSensitive file and module names.  Are you developing on different platforms to your production (Windows vs *nix)?  Check that your module names are in the form of `Module_Lowercasenamesonlyworkhere`.

------EDIT------

Try installing Alanstorm's ConfigViewer module or CommerceBug extension from his website, that will show you the "complied" config for all the admin modules.  You can then see if your `adminhtml` nodes are being included.  That's the only way that I'm aware of that will confirm that your config is being read by Magento, which sounds like the issue.

Comment: We have already checked. there isn't any issues related case sensitive